# Some kind of fundamental lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

I remember having read something like

> Let $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and connected and let $u \in L^1_{loc}(X\times Y)$ with 
>   $$ \int_X \int_Y u \, \mathrm{div}_y \, \varphi \, dydx = 0$$
>   for all $\varphi \in \left(C_0^\infty(X \times Y)\right)^n$. 
>   Then $u$ does not depend on $y$.

and I tried to proof it, but I failed. Now I wonder if this Lemma is even valid, or if I just didn't try hard enough.

Any help is appreciated :)

edit: Of course, the following version should also hold:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and connected and let $u \in L^1_{loc}(X)$ with 
>   $$ \int_X u \, \mathrm{div} \, \varphi \, dx = 0$$
>   for all $\varphi \in \left(C_0^\infty(X)\right)^n$. 
>   Then $u$ is constant almost everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure integration is correct here? $y\in X$ and $x\in Y$ from the symbols. Regarding the proof: Try to compute $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}$ of the expression and see if you can deduct $u_y = 0$.

Comment: @AlexR deduce, not deduct (the difference matters here)

Comment: @AlexR Just google 'deduce vs deduct'

Comment: @Danu Thanks yet again :)